# IdentityServer4 behind Nginx Ingress, deployed with Terraform and Helm: not all users can login

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, terraform, identityserver4, nginx-ingress

I have a Kubernetes cluster where I'm deploying two containers with a web page (Asp.Net Core with Kestrel, React) and with the identity server 4. The ingress controller I'm using is Nginx-ingress. The identity server is configured to use Oidc implicit flow against an Azure Active Directory app registrations. One user can login successfully into the web page and two others cannot: they see 502 errors or "page cannot be reached". The nginx logs shows the Oidc flow going correctly up to the second call to the `/identityserver/External/Callback` path. There is no indication as why this calls are stripped of details.

The things I've tried were from those [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635169/configure-identityserver4-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48964429/net-core-behind-nginx-returns-502-bad-gateway-after-authentication-by-identitys), but to no avail.

> 12.25.114.244 - [12.25.114.244] - - [08/Aug/2019:14:35:59 +0000] "POST /identityserver/signin-oidc HTTP/2.0" 302 0
>   "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/SAS/ProcessAuth"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134" 2518
>   0.222 [default-identityserver-9000] 10.244.0.40:9000 0 0.220 302 8249f8f3ce72756bf8f2cfa1cc2faf3d
>   12.25.114.244 - [12.25.114.244] - - [08/Aug/2019:14:35:59 +0000] "-" 000 0 "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/SAS/ProcessAuth"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134" 5604
>   0.000 [] - - - - a162031b9747a7b9ff8d281265d62d4f
>   12.25.114.244 - [12.25.114.244] - - [08/Aug/2019:14:35:59 +0000] "-" 000 0 "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/SAS/ProcessAuth"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134" 5870
>   0.000 [] - - - - 6f2e99f98fdb7cb367134572fbf52c37
>   12.25.114.244 - [12.25.114.244] - - [08/Aug/2019:14:35:59 +0000] "-" 000 0 "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/SAS/ProcessAuth"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134" 5870
>   0.000 [] - - - - 2837e78e72ef64edd27078ae6b2d2b4b
>   12.25.114.244 - [12.25.114.244] - - [08/Aug/2019:14:35:59 +0000] "-" 000 0 "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/SAS/ProcessAuth"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134" 5870
>   0.000 [] - - - - 1de946ed242f391dadfb78bb9f72bfdc
>   12.25.114.244 - [12.25.114.244] - - [08/Aug/2019:14:35:59 +0000] "-" 000 0 "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/SAS/ProcessAuth"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134" 5870
>   0.000 [] - - - - 4b441be747adb2c29f10d55568dc4e64
>   12.25.114.244 - [12.25.114.244] - - [08/Aug/2019:14:36:00 +0000] "-" 000 0 "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/SAS/ProcessAuth"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134" 5870
>   0.000 [] - - - - dce572bd77990586010372c156fff9be
>   12.25.114.244 - [12.25.114.244] - - [08/Aug/2019:14:36:00 +0000] "-" 000 0 "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/SAS/ProcessAuth"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134" 5870
>   0.000 [] - - - - fc2094d7a449925eccc9b525f908b477

Is there anything I miss on why two users cannot login while the other can?

Later Edit:
There are pieces which need to be added here for the complete picture. Terraform is used to deploy to Kubernetes, using a Helm provider and a Helm chart for Nginx-Ingress.

Comment: `"POST /identityserver/signin-oidc HTTP/2.0" 302 0 ` seems there's a redirect. Is your initial call going to http and gets then redirected? Or is your nginx the SSL termination endpoint and proxies the calls as http to the application? The later is fine (no need to encrypt internal traffic), but nginx needs to send forward headers `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-For`. However, if you are using ASP.NET Core 2.1/2.2, added `UseHsts/UseHttpRedirection` which may cause endless loops in some constellations that aren't hosted in IIS, so you'd need to register the forwarded header yourself

Comment: Usually the forwarded headers get registered as part of `UseIISIntegration`. In ASP.NET Core 3 this issue will be addressed with an `ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED` environment variable (see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/forwarded-headers-middleware-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-6/) and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.2#forward-the-scheme-for-linux-and-non-iis-reverse-proxies so you may add this one. If that works, I'd promote the comments to an answer, its a common issue/source of problems in OAuth/OIDC flows

Comment: @Tseng would this explain that for one user works and for the others doesn't? I'm expecting that no login would happen if headers are not forwarded.

Comment: @Tseng I will try your solution above and get back with an answer.

Comment: Are the users on different machines? HSTS sets an expiration date (usually a year) where the browser will cache HSTS settings (and hard to remove it from cache). But could also be that the other users called it via http for some reason and one that works already had HSTS cache entry before. If HSTS is set, it will cause browser to automatically turn http in https before peforming the request (in the past you usually did http request and the server would redirect you to https, which is vulnerable to a badly configured website or user entry to submit sensitive data via http)

Comment: Yes, they are on different machines. There is no `UseHsts/UseHttpRedirection` on Asp.Net Core 2.2 and all users always used `https://...`

Comment: @Tseng the forwarded headers, disabling hsts and UseHttpRedirection didn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635169/configure-identityserver4-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48964429/net-core-behind-nginx-returns-502-bad-gateway-after-authentication-by-identitys), as well as this [Github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3499), are useful but Terraform needs a template file to specify those annotations and config values. Here is what I've ended up with:

```
data "template_file" "nginx-ingress" {
    template = <<EOF
controller:
  config: 
    http2-max-field-size: "16k"
    http2-max-header-size: "64k"
    proxy-buffer-size: "64k"
EOF
}
```

And the `helm_release` provider needs its `values` to be set:

```
resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress" {
  values = [
    "${data.template_file.nginx-ingress.rendered}"
  ]
}
```